# Difference between k-gram index approach and standard python string methods in handling wildCard query

Tags: python, wildcard, information-retrieval

how does the k-gram method stand out in handling wildCard query (from what I read online almost every institute is using this method)?

I know for bi-gram you break the word into bi-char sequences, for example, `mon*` becomes `$m`, `mo`, `on` (of course you need to maintain a secondary index postings) and you AND these sequences which will return intersections of words that satisfy the AND condition.

But wouldn't simple python `string.startswith(str)` which also checks if a term starting with `str` work simpler(or maybe better) than the k-gram method ?

Should I use `string.startswith(str)` for the sake of simplicity ?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `str.startswith` would yield false positives. take for instance the case of `state` and `stationary` not to mention having to scan a large problem space

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes, that could be a case I didn't think about! But for the k-gram indexes, in which step do we create secondary index for each k-gram ? Is it done when we build our standard inverted index for each term ?

Comment: that’s one way to do it yes, associate the k-grams with the record indexes that they match